# Vue3 counter and const form in setup()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I don't understand, please help.
I have a counter that works through a setup, and I also have a form that is in the same setup, how can I combine them?

My code:

```
setup(props) {
    const form = useForm({
        name: props.user.name,
    })
    function update_shopItem() {
        form.put(route('user.update', props.user.id))
    }
    return { form, update_shopItem }
    
    
    
    const count = ref(1)
    return {
        count
    };

},
```

I know that this is because there are two returns and only the first one is executed and after the code is interrupted, but how can I make it work otherwise that all the code inside the setup was executed? Tell me please.
I want to make the counter work regardless of the const form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use one return that takes the different properties :

```js
setup(props) {
    const form = useForm({
        name: props.user.name,
    })
    function update_shopItem() {
        form.put(route('user.update', props.user.id))
    }

    const count = ref(1)

    return { form, update_shopItem, count}
},
```